# Can I use async/await to accelerate init classes?

Tags: python-3.7, python-asyncio

I'm a python starter, and I'm trying to write some data analysis programs. the program is like below:

```
import asyncio
import time


class Test:
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task
        time.sleep(5)  # here's some other jobs...
        print(f'{self.task = }')


async def main():
    result = []
    tasks = ['task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4', 'task5', 'task6', 'task7', 'task8', 'task9']
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # I have a program structure like this, can I use async?
    # how to start init tasks at almost the same time?
    for task in tasks:
        result.append(Test(task))
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")


asyncio.run(main())
```

I've tried some other way like multiprocessing, it works, code like below:

```
...
def main():
    result = []
    tasks = ['task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4', 'task5', 'task6', 'task7', 'task8', 'task9']
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # I have a program structure like this, can I use async?
    # how to start init tasks at the same time?
    p = Pool()
    result = p.map(operation, [(task,) for task in tasks])
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
...
```

but I still want to learn some 'modern way' to do this.  I've found a module named 'ray', it's new.
But could async do this? I'm still wondering...
If someone can give me some advice, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code won't necessarily benefit from async IO, because `__init__` is not "awaitable". You might be able to benefit from async if your code were structured differently and has an appropriate bottleneck. For example, if we had:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self):
        <some not io bound stuff>
        <some io bound task>
```

We could re-structure this to:

```
    class Task:
    def __init__(self):
        <some not io bound stuff>

    async def prime(self):
        await <some io bound task>
```

Then in your main loop you can initialise the tasks as you're doing, then run the slow `prime` step in your event loop.

My advice here though would be to resist doing this unless you know you definitely have a problem. Coroutines can be quite fiddly, so you should only do this if you need to do it!

Comment: that means if I want to use 'async', I need something to 'await', and I could set the job which needs lot of time 'awaitable' with 'async def', is that right? and then? async could do the rest for me automatically?

Comment: Roughly. It only applies if the slow task is IO bound though. For CPU bound tasks you might need to look at multithreading